# Cannot update core with composer after switching to core-recommended

Tags: 8, composer

I tried to update core from 8.9.0 to 8.9.1 with `composer require drupal/core-recommended:8.9.1` but I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.1, 8.9.0].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.1, 8.9.0].
- Can only install one of: drupal/core[8.9.1, 8.9.0].
- drupal/core-recommended 8.9.1 requires drupal/core 8.9.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.1].
- Installation request for drupal/core-recommended 8.9.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[8.9.1].
- Installation request for drupal/core (locked at 8.9.0) -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.9.0].
```

This is pretty confusing, I thought drupal/core was replaced by drupal/recommended?

Comment: Look in your `composer.json` file to see if `drupal/core` is listed, and what it's set to.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/update-drupal-core-via-composer) `require` should be used when updating to unstable/dev, try using `composer update drupal/core-recommended --with-dependencies` instead.

Comment: I think this is because your composer.json requires `drupal/core` instead of `drupal/core-recommended`. Since core-recommended requires a new version of core, you're getting this clash when you try to require core-recommended (your new requirement requires core:8.9.1 while your composer.json still requires core:8.9.0)

Comment: When I updated from 8.7. to 8.9. `drupal/core` disappeared from composer.json, now it's only `"drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8"`.
`composer update`: I think the docs are not quite accurate in this case. You definitely need ´require´ if you want to install a specific version, not only unstable or dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again with `composer require drupal/core-recommended:8.9.1 --update-with-dependencies` and it started to update core. Unfortunately drupal/core-composer-scaffold was not touched so I had to update it directly with an extra composer command.

Also I noticed that both of these were updated, I hope it is right:

```
- Updating drupal/core (8.9.0 => 8.9.1): Downloading (100%)
- Updating drupal/core-recommended (8.9.0 => 8.9.1)
```